# How can I implement javascript in order to base the background of my posts on a color generated by the title of the post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been looking into designing my posts to generate a background color based on the length of the title of the post, of which I was inspired by newswordy.com.

A page I'm working on in particular is:

https://gametilldawn.com/article/the-real-console-war/

The following code is a snippet that I began working with from this link:
https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-40.php

```
function random_bg_color() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
    console.log("bgColor")

    document.body.style.background = bgColor;
    }

random_bg_color();
```

I have also attempted a variant at targeting div class="fl-page-content", instead of document.body.style.background but it didn't produce any colors on said post.

```
function random_bg_color() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
 console.log(bgColor);

    .fl-page-content = bgColor;
    }

random_bg_color();
```

I also have looked into the matter further and came across this link also, almost about the same idea:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/random-background-color

**My question is what might I aim at in the site's code, in order to generate this in the custom post type Article?** After running the aforementioned code, it worked, but only on the admin login page. I'm still new to working with Javascript, but help is appreciated!

PS - I did reach out to the coders and designers of that site and did get a response that led me to it being Javascript as the vehicle, but the company itself hasn't answered yet the two emails I've sent them over a month's span.

Comment: I placed that within the info in case there was a way that what I'm asking for can be done in another format besides Javascript, for which I'm trying.

Comment: Another format could have been anything; you should have been precise about it, IMHO.

Comment: Would you prefer that I simply remove it and leave just Javascript? Then we could look into the question itself?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: "what might I aim at in the site's code, in order to generate this in the custom post type Article?" In another way, based on the code provided, how should I target the title of the Article so that it's length can generate a background color?

Comment: This would be a much more elegant question if you provided the actual markup you are trying to target/set background on.  I for one do not click links on questions without knowing for sure what they are.  It should be a self contained question.

Comment: I'm going to edit the post so that you can see the exact coding that is present and what I'm looking into is why is it not working. I've already stated what I'm targeting, but it doesn't seem to be affecting the current page. There's also an answer for which I'm looking into now and thinking over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got the question right but here's a code snippet which sets the background color based on the post title's length:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div class="fl-page-content">
     <h1 class="fl-heading">
          <span class="fl-heading-text">The Real Console War</span>
        </h1>
      <p>
        Hello dear reader!
      </p>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function setBgColor() {
        var titleLength = document.getElementsByClassName('fl-heading-text')[0].innerText.length;
    var hue = titleLength * 100 % 360;
    var bgColor = "hsl( " + hue + ", 90%, 60% )";
    document.getElementsByClassName("fl-page-content")[0].style.background = bgColor;
}

setBgColor();
```

Demo: [https://jsfiddle.net/L01r1xmc/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/L01r1xmc/)

Comment: I've played around with the JS to attempt to target the h1. 
I'm not too familar with this, but my h1 appears as this in Chrome Dev Tools:  
     <h1 class="fl-heading">
 <span class="fl-heading-text">The Real Console War</span>
     </h1>

Going to run this and attempt to see if it works.

Comment: I updated the snippet and the example with the new heading structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've implemented this code and it works to my liking. I can play around a bit more and tweak a few things, but you nailed it even with my poorly worded question. This was my first experience with the community; I'll get better.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, and is, in fact, changing the background color, but you just can't see it since the `body` element is being covered by other elements.

You'll need to change your code a bit if you want to change the background color of specific elements.

```
function random_bg_color() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
  console.log("bgColor")
  document.querySelector('div.fl-builder-content').style.background = bgColor; // Changes the main content's background
  document.querySelector('.fl-row-content-wrap').style.background = bgColor; // Changes the header's background
}
random_bg_color();
```

Comment: Thank you! You got me thinking in the right direction.